Direct limit topology and subspaces
Let $X$ be a topological space and let $X_1\subset X_2\subset \dots$ be a
sequence of closed subspaces such that $X$ is the direct limit of the subspaces $X_i$,
i.e. $U\subset X$ is open if and only if each $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X+i$.
Now let $A\subset X$ be a subspace. From my understanding Fritsch-Piccini in their book
``cellular structures in topology''
https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4493/1/4493.pdf
in Proposition A.5.4 (page 275) claim that if all the $X_i$ are normal,
then $A$ is the direct limit of the subspaces $A\cap X_i$.
This statement is very convenient, but I am pretty sure that the proof they provide does not make sense (the proposition has two statements, the above is Statement (2), the proof builds on Statement (1) about closures, which I think is just incorrect).
Does anybody know whether the above statement is correct, and if yes, what is the proof? My attempts at proving the statement failed miserably.

What don't you believe about Prop A.5.4?

I don't believe in the proof. The statement also seems to be too good to be true (if it was was true, I would think you'd see it more often). I am pretty sure I have a counterexample to Statement (1) of Proposition A.5.4. In the proof it says ``Using the normality condition over and over again, one finds inductively
open sets '', but the proof does not say how this is supposed to work and I don't see how this works. All possible attempts I can think of run into troubles and don't work.

It's true if $A$ is either open or closed in $X$, and this holds without the assumption of normality.
For a counterexample to the general case let
$$X_n=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(1/i,0)\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{(1/j,1/k)\mid k\in\mathbb{N},\;j\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$$
toplogised as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X$ be the colimit of the sequence $X_1\subseteq X_2\subset\dots$. Note that the topology on $X$ is finer than the euclidean topology, since for instance the diagonal sequence $\{(1/n,1/n)\}_\mathbb{N}$ does not converge to $(0,0)$.
Now put $A=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(1/j,1/k)\mid j,k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. The set $D=\{(1/j,1/k)\mid j,k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $X$ and hence not closed $A$. However, $D$ is closed in $colim(A\cap X_n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In particular, $A$ is not the colimit of the sequence $A\cap X_1\subseteq A\cap X_2\subseteq\dots$
In this example, the $X_n$'s are compact metric spaces, so $X$ is perfectly normal and paracompact. Moreover $A$ is both a $G_\delta$- and $F_\sigma$-subset of $X$.
Here is a positive result. Say that a space $X$ is determined hereditarily by an increasing cover of subspaces $X_1\subseteq X_2\subseteq \dots$ if $(i)$ $X=colim_n(X_n)$, and $(ii)$ if $A\subseteq X$ is any subspace, then $A=colim_n(A\cap X_n)$.

Proposition Let $X$ be the colimit of an increasing sequence $X_1\subseteq X_2\subseteq\dots$. Then a necessary and sufficient condition that $X$ be determined hereditarily by the cover $\{X_n\}_\mathbb{N}$ is that for any subspace $A\subseteq X$ and any $x\in cl_X(A)$ there is $n$ such that $x\in cl_{X_n}(A\cap X_n)$. $\qquad\blacksquare$


thanks for your remarks! Do you have a reference for the first paragraph, why it's true for closed subsets? Or an idea where one could look?

It's easy: consider the map obvious map $\pi:\bigsqcup_\mathbb{N}X_n\rightarrow X$. Then $X$ is the colimit of the $X_n$ if and only if $\pi$ is quotient. Now it's just a standard statement about quotient maps.

Thanks, I now see it! The condition on normality was a red herring.

Incidentally, the proposition I give at the end is just the statement that the map $\pi$ is hereditarily quotient (i.e. pseudo-open).
